# javascript onclick not firing when expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set a boolean value depending on if a checkbox is checked or not, but I my checkQA click function doesn't seem to be firing.

`console.log(checkbox)` returns `input#enableQA` so I know it's hitting the correct element.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coaofpzL/).

```
var isChecked = false,
    checkbox = document.getElementById('enableQA');

checkbox.onclick = checkQA;

var checkQA = function () {

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        isChecked = true;
        checkbox.checked = true;
        alert(isChecked);
    } else {
        isChecked = false;
        checkbox.checked = false;
        alert(isChecked);
    }
}

<form method="post" name="qaform">
    <input id="enableQA" name="enableQA" type="checkbox" value="" />
    Enable QA
</form>
```

I'm only interested in a pure Javascript solution, please don't suggest jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checkQA` will be undefined by its assigned to `onclick`. So move that assignment later after the function. Or don't make it a variable function, but a named function.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp :

```
    var isChecked = false,
    checkbox = document.getElementById('enableQA');

console.log(checkbox);

checkbox.onclick  = function () {

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        isChecked = true;
        checkbox.checked = true;
        alert(isChecked);
    } else {
        isChecked = false;
        checkbox.checked = false;
        alert(isChecked);
    }
}
```

It's working for me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick function doesn't exist yet at the moment you are assigning it to the onclick. Switch the order around like this:

```
    var isChecked = false,
    checkbox = document.getElementById('enableQA');

var checkQA = function () {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        isChecked = true;
        checkbox.checked = true;
        alert(isChecked);
    } else {
        isChecked = false;
        checkbox.checked = false;
        alert(isChecked);
    }
}

checkbox.onclick = checkQA;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/coaofpzL/3/